# Filtering table view using fetched results controller without Search Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I've got a UITableView using an NSFetchedResults controller to populate the table like so:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Expense" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"expenseDate" ascending:NO];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

I want to be able to filter the results, but for a few different reasons, I don't want to have to use a Search Bar and Search Display Controller.

Is there anyway I can filter the results using my own predicate and then reload the table?

Answer (score 0):

After fetch your results, you will have a new Array of data to populate through the `UITableView`, then you can call:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Sure - but how do I go about fetching these new results? Am I able to just do a new fetch request on the fetch controller and execute it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can add a NSPredicate to your NSFetchRequest and then perform a new fetch with your NSFetchedResultsController.

Here's an example of when I did something similar:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Expense" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"expenseDate" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    //Apply your filtering predicate to the fetchRequest if necessary
    NSPredicate *filterPrediate = [self getFilterPredicate];
    if(filterPrediate){
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPrediate];
    }

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;

}

- (NSPredicate *)getFilterPredicate
{
    //Get or create your filtering predicate here.
    //You can combine NSPredicates using a NSCompoundPredicate if necessary.
    if(shouldFilter){
        return yourNSPrecicate;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)reloadFetchedViewController
{
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

Then to update the UITableView with a new query:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self reloadFetchedViewController];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Another additional note: never use self.fetchedResultsController within its own instantiation method. Use _fetchedResultsController instead